# Samba and NFS conflicts?

Tags: server, samba, nfs

I'm using NFS server for quite some time now, and never needed a samba share. But now I'll need to connect one Windows PC to a network, and I should use samba share on the same server.
I'd like to install samba and set it up, but without touching the current NFS configurations for the rest of the LAN, is this possible, dangerous in any way? It's very important to me that the current NFS configuration stays untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that your SAMBA or NFS will interfere with each other in any way.
Different protocols , different ports. And I've used both on the same server without issues.

But if your machine is in a production environment and are worried about installing things. You should have a copy of your production environment, a test study environment where you can try things out. and then move the features you have tested in to your production environment.

Comment: It's not a production environment, it's my home server, but I hate messing up things that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience I can clearly say: NO, there is no interference. I did a parallell share of the same files for the same users in SMB and in NFS (simultaneously, same machines, same files, same users). Absolutely no interference.